# Cant Start NVIDIA performance mode

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kubuntu, intel-graphics, 14.04

[image: ERROR]

What does this error means?
Is not possible to select the NVIDIA GPU, whenever I try this blank error appears and returns immediately to to Intel Graphics

I just upgraded to Kubuntu 14.04, but before this I didn't use any NVIDIA drivers. At first when I selected the new Driver(at first I selected the recommended option):

[image]

The system info reported the NVIDIA was in use, even after restart, but then after opening a wine program, the screen died (only on that session).

After some time trying kernel fallback and other things like the system suggested (sudo apt-get -f install) I was able to login, but now I cant use NVIDIA.

The GPU is GEFORCE 720M.